# Raspberry has no internet but is connected to my router

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

I have a raspberry with raspbian intstalled with no gui (I think its called jessie)

The first days it work exactly like I wanted it to work but since yesterday it has no internet even if the wlan cable is plugged in.

I've seen a couple of solutions but that is if you have a wireless conection with gui.

I dont think its my router because every other device works on there and the other days it also worked with that router

please help
thanks, Stephan

PS: Im sorry for my bad english, Im from the Netherlands and the ipconfig results are the same with no cable plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simpel,

I just needed to

```
sudo dhcpcd
```

Because the service wouldnt start when it booted up.